# Record rtp stream with FFMPEG can not save files less than 256Kb

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp

I'm using ffmpeg to record only audio rtp stream it's work ok. But if recorded file less than 256Kb ffmpeg is not save the file. I received a new file 0Kb(error). If recorded file greater than 256Kb ffmpeg only save file when 256, 512, 768, 1024,.... Kb.

Comment: Hi, you question is missing some information that will help answering you. Please supply a clear definition of your problem and your work environment - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What OS are you using?